# Object double data binding

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to bind a specific value of an array of objects on an ng-repeat in a table with in-line editing.

The problem that I'm encountering is that my object doesn't have the same value on each ng-repeat.

Example object:

```
var products = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 20
},
{   
    id: 2,
    value: {
        finalValue: 30,
        customValue: 10
    }
}];
```

To my knowledge if I return just the primitive value it won't be binded. I have the property names to get to the specific value on each ng-repeat. For example I have on my first iteration the way to get to the value is just `value` and the second one has to be `value.finalValue`.

To my knowledge... to bind the value I can not return just the primitive value `20` or `30`, I have to return an object. So my first try was to create a function in my controller that does a `property.split('.')` and return an array with the object that contains the value and the property to get to it.

Eg) on my first iteration it would return:

```
[{ id: 1, value: 20 }, 'value']
```

On the second iteration it would return:

```
[{ finalValue: 30, customValue: 10 }, 'finalValue']
```

And now this will be binded to the actual model, but how can I display this on my template?

I can do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products>
    {{ getValueObj(product) }}
</div>
```

But how can I display the value itself? Something like `results[0][results[1]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not on your `ngRepeat` do something like:

```
ng-repeat="product in products"
```

and in your **binding** do something like:

```
{{product.value.finalValue || product.value}}
```

The full example will be something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products>
 {{product.value.finalValue || product.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your replay, the problem is that I don't have just 2 different properties. Sometimes is nested one more level with a different property name, etc.

Comment: @user1364649 sounds like you need to standardize your model instead of adapting the view

Comment: I wish I could. Unfortunately it's an object that an API is returning.